# How to use the attrs in forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput()

Tags: css, django, forms, widget

I'm trying to create a custom fields in Django
I'm not sure this is the right approach, but I keep getting an error I can't understand`enter code here`

```
AttributeError: 'CharField' object has no attribute 'attrs'
```

Here is my code. Can anyone explain what's going on?

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'email', 'password', 'confirm_password')

    widgets = {
        'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "form-control input-lg",
                                           'placeholder': "نام کاربری *",
                                           'name': 'display_name',
                                           'required': "required",
                                           'tabindex': "3",
                                           'data-error': "password is required"}),
        'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': "form-control input-lg",
                                         'placeholder': 'ایمیل *',
                                         'name': 'email',
                                         'required': "required",
                                         'tabindex': "4",
                                         'data-error': "email is required"}),
        'confirm_password': forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': "form-control input-lg",
                                                                              'placeholder': "تکرار رمز *",
                                                                              'name': 'confirm_password',
                                                                              'required': "required",
                                                                              'tabindex': "6",
                                                                              'data-error': "confirm password is required"})),
        'password': forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"class": "form-control input-lg",
                                                                      'placeholder': " رمز *",
                                                                      'name': 'password',
                                                                      'required': "required",
                                                                      'tabindex': "5",
                                                                      'data-error': " password is required"})),

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't use the `widgets` parameter correctly. The values you set for the `confirm password` and `password` are fields when they should be widgets. You should be using `forms.PasswordInput` directly.

If you want to customize the classes which are used for the form's fields instead of having them derived from the ones specified in the model you need to provide the `field_classes` attribute.